# First story with a portal to a distant location?

Tags: history-of, teleportation

I believe the idea of teleportation or extremely fast movement is very old. "Seven League Boots" and probably inexplicable movement to a distant place effected by a geni or demon.

I am interested in a doorway etc. into another distant place with ideally a non-magical explanation but even a magical doorway is of interest.

Comment: Apparently (says Wikipedia) there is a story from 1877 (Edward Page Mitchell's , The Man Without a Body) where somebody transmitted a cat through a telegraph wire (also his head, hence the title). Does not really qualify as a portal,  but I was quite impressed that the idea is so old.

Comment: As usual, religious works are off limits, I suppose?

Comment: @EikePierstorff: I remember an old cartoon where a bicycle messenger is riding on the telegraph lines -- when telegraphy was new, I guess some people had trouble understanding how messages were sent. So perhaps this idea for the story had its origin in this kind of misconception.

Comment: @releseabe not sure - only some ten years later, Robert Duncan Milne wrote "Professor Vehr's Electrical Experiment", in which a similar process was described as deconstructing a person into electrical waves and send them through a wire the same way as sound waves (a somewhat tongue in cheek story in which a character used the invention to travel from SF to New Orleans to retrieve his bride that had been whisked away by her dissenting parents). I just don't think anything using wires would qualify as portal.

Comment: @EikePierstorff:in 1887 was the idea that energy was equivalent to matter "in the air"? Perhaps it was. This also is sort of an early TV idea which people probably starting thinking about when the first fax was invented (which as we know predated the telephone, amazingly).

Answer (score 1):

The earliest I remember at the moment is the short story, "It's Such A Beautiful Day", by Isaac Asimov, published in 1955.

They have transportation using "Doors".  The story is about a boy in the first community to be built entirely using Doors.  This boy's Door malfunctions and he does something that is Just Not Done and walks to school.  And again...

His mother thinks there is something wrong and takes him to a psychologist or psychiatrist....

Comment: I'm sure some of the experts out there will beat this date, but we need to start somewhere....

Answer (score 1):

Less "science fiction" than my other answer, and more fantastic, but older, is "The Door in the Wall", ashort story by H. G. Wells first published in the Daily Chronicle in 1906.

A boy walks through a door and finds himself in a wonderful garden with happy people, etc., but is somehow 'sent' back to the 'real' world.  No one believes him and he wants to return there.  He occasionally sees the door but always when he is too busy to enter.  He comes to regret this, but nonetheless never goes through it.

The story ends in a Twilight Zone type of way, (quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Door_in_the_Wall_(short_story))):

> The narrator ends by telling us that Wallace's body has just been
> found at the bottom of an excavation, and that he had in poor light
> walked through a small doorway that led onto it. Perhaps this shows
> that the green door in the wall never existed. "By our daylight
> standard he walked out of security into darkness, danger, and death.
> But did he see like that?"

So....will this count, for the purposes of this question?  Was there really such a portal, in the world of this story?  We don't know.

Comment: I think this answer is a bit to fantasy based, and not enough sci-fi.

Comment: @Questor - I was definitely wondering that; we'll see what the OP thinks I guess.